# Reverse Engineer AES key using injection request

Tags: algorithm, encryption, aes, reverse-engineering, caesar-cipher

I was trying to reverse engineer a mobile application, trying to get the secret keys so I can send a request using cURL from my local machine, anyways I had before this challenge which I solved it using Frida server, but Unfortunately this time I'm facing a big challenge to bypass AES encryption.

the mobile application may uses many Encryption algorithm to hide the request from MITM.
so I decomplied the the mobile application and I found that the application using may **AES/GCM/NoPadding** and **AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding**
here is the code :

```
package f.a.a;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.security.KeyPairGeneratorSpec;
import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
import android.util.Base64;
import f.a.a.d;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.UnrecoverableEntryException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;

/* compiled from: EncryptionManager */
public class b {

    /* renamed from: a  reason: collision with root package name */
    private KeyStore f18695a;

    /* renamed from: b  reason: collision with root package name */
    private SecretKey f18696b;

    /* renamed from: c  reason: collision with root package name */
    private SecretKey f18697c;

    /* renamed from: d  reason: collision with root package name */
    private RSAPublicKey f18698d;

    /* renamed from: e  reason: collision with root package name */
    private RSAPrivateKey f18699e;

    /* renamed from: f  reason: collision with root package name */
    private boolean f18700f = false;

    /* renamed from: g  reason: collision with root package name */
    private Context f18701g;

    /* renamed from: h  reason: collision with root package name */
    SharedPreferences f18702h;

    /* renamed from: i  reason: collision with root package name */
    d.c f18703i;

    /* compiled from: EncryptionManager */
    public static class a {

        /* renamed from: a  reason: collision with root package name */
        byte[] f18704a = null;

        /* renamed from: b  reason: collision with root package name */
        byte[] f18705b = null;

        /* renamed from: c  reason: collision with root package name */
        byte[] f18706c = null;

        /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
        public byte[] a() {
            byte[] bArr = this.f18704a;
            byte[] bArr2 = new byte[(bArr.length + this.f18705b.length)];
            System.arraycopy(bArr, 0, bArr2, 0, bArr.length);
            byte[] bArr3 = this.f18705b;
            System.arraycopy(bArr3, 0, bArr2, this.f18704a.length, bArr3.length);
            return bArr2;
        }
    }

    /* renamed from: f.a.a.b$b  reason: collision with other inner class name */
    /* compiled from: EncryptionManager */
    public class C0319b extends GeneralSecurityException {
        public C0319b() {
            super("Invalid Mac, failed to verify integrity.");
        }
    }

    public b(Context context, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, d.c cVar) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableEntryException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalStateException {
        boolean z = false;
        this.f18700f = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(v("sps_data_in_compat"), Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23);
        this.f18703i = cVar;
        this.f18701g = context;
        this.f18702h = sharedPreferences;
        B();
        try {
            D(context, sharedPreferences);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            if (y(e2)) {
                z = H(e2);
            } else {
                throw e2;
            }
        }
        if (z) {
            D(context, sharedPreferences);
        }
    }

    static String E(byte[] bArr) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int length = bArr.length;
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < length; i2++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", new Object[]{Byte.valueOf(bArr[i2])}));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] c(String str) {
        return Base64.decode(str, 2);
    }

    public static String d(byte[] bArr) {
        return Base64.encodeToString(bArr, 2);
    }

    public static String v(String str) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return E(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(str.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public void A(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) throws KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
        if (this.f18700f) {
            this.f18696b = u(sharedPreferences);
            this.f18697c = x(sharedPreferences);
        } else if (this.f18695a.containsAlias("sps_aes_key") && this.f18695a.entryInstanceOf("sps_aes_key", KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry.class)) {
            this.f18696b = ((KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) this.f18695a.getEntry("sps_aes_key", (KeyStore.ProtectionParameter) null)).getSecretKey();
        }
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public void B() throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        KeyStore instance = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        this.f18695a = instance;
        instance.load((KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter) null);
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public void C() throws KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        if (this.f18695a.containsAlias("sps_rsa_key") && this.f18695a.entryInstanceOf("sps_rsa_key", KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry.class)) {
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) this.f18695a.getEntry("sps_rsa_key", (KeyStore.ProtectionParameter) null);
            this.f18698d = (RSAPublicKey) privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();
            this.f18699e = (RSAPrivateKey) privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();
        }
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public void D(Context context, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) throws NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException {
        r(context, sharedPreferences);
        A(sharedPreferences);
    }

    public byte[] F(a aVar) throws NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, IOException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, C0319b {
        boolean z;
        byte[] bArr;
        try {
            bArr = h(aVar);
            z = false;
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            if (y(e2)) {
                z = H(e2);
                bArr = null;
            } else {
                throw e2;
            }
        }
        if (!z) {
            return bArr;
        }
        D(this.f18701g, this.f18702h);
        return h(aVar);
    }

    public a G(byte[] bArr) throws NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableEntryException {
        boolean z;
        a aVar;
        try {
            aVar = l(bArr);
            z = false;
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            if (y(e2)) {
                z = H(e2);
                aVar = null;
            } else {
                throw e2;
            }
        }
        if (!z) {
            return aVar;
        }
        D(this.f18701g, this.f18702h);
        return l(bArr);
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public <T extends Exception> boolean H(T t) {
        d.c cVar = this.f18703i;
        return cVar != null && cVar.a(t, this.f18695a, z());
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public boolean I(byte[] bArr, byte[] bArr2) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        if (bArr == null || bArr2 == null) {
            return false;
        }
        byte[] e2 = e(bArr2);
        if (e2.length != bArr.length) {
            return false;
        }
        byte b2 = 0;
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < e2.length; i2++) {
            b2 |= e2[i2] ^ bArr[i2];
        }
        if (b2 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public byte[] a(byte[] bArr) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
        Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL");
        instance.init(2, this.f18699e);
        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bArr), instance);
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        while (true) {
            int read = cipherInputStream.read();
            if (read == -1) {
                break;
            }
            arrayList.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) read));
        }
        int size = arrayList.size();
        byte[] bArr2 = new byte[size];
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < size; i2++) {
            bArr2[i2] = ((Byte) arrayList.get(i2)).byteValue();
        }
        cipherInputStream.close();
        return bArr2;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public byte[] b(byte[] bArr) throws KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
        Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL");
        instance.init(1, this.f18698d);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream, instance);
        cipherOutputStream.write(bArr);
        cipherOutputStream.close();
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public byte[] e(byte[] bArr) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        Mac instance = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        instance.init(this.f18697c);
        return instance.doFinal(bArr);
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public a f(String str) {
        a aVar = new a();
        String[] split = str.split("]");
        aVar.f18704a = c(split[0]);
        aVar.f18705b = c(split[1]);
        if (split.length > 2) {
            aVar.f18706c = c(split[2]);
        }
        return aVar;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public String g(String str) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, C0319b, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableEntryException {
        if (str == null || str.length() <= 0) {
            return null;
        }
        byte[] F = F(f(str));
        return new String(F, 0, F.length, "UTF-8");
    }

    public byte[] h(a aVar) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, C0319b, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException {
        if (aVar == null || aVar.f18705b == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (this.f18700f) {
            return j(aVar);
        }
        return i(aVar);
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    @TargetApi(19)
    public byte[] i(a aVar) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        instance.init(2, this.f18696b, new GCMParameterSpec(128, aVar.f18704a));
        return instance.doFinal(aVar.f18705b);
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public byte[] j(a aVar) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, C0319b {
        if (I(aVar.f18706c, aVar.a())) {
            Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
            instance.init(2, this.f18696b, new IvParameterSpec(aVar.f18704a));
            return instance.doFinal(aVar.f18705b);
        }
        throw new C0319b();
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public String k(a aVar) {
        if (aVar.f18706c != null) {
            return d(aVar.f18704a) + "]" + d(aVar.f18705b) + "]" + d(aVar.f18706c);
        }
        return d(aVar.f18704a) + "]" + d(aVar.f18705b);
    }

    public a l(byte[] bArr) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IOException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        if (bArr == null || bArr.length <= 0) {
            return null;
        }
        byte[] w = w();
        if (this.f18700f) {
            return o(bArr, w);
        }
        return n(bArr, w);
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public String m(String str) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException, BadPaddingException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableEntryException {
        if (str == null || str.length() <= 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return k(G(str.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    @TargetApi(19)
    public a n(byte[] bArr, byte[] bArr2) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        instance.init(1, this.f18696b, new GCMParameterSpec(128, bArr2));
        a aVar = new a();
        aVar.f18704a = instance.getIV();
        aVar.f18705b = instance.doFinal(bArr);
        return aVar;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public a o(byte[] bArr, byte[] bArr2) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
        instance.init(1, this.f18696b, new IvParameterSpec(bArr2));
        a aVar = new a();
        aVar.f18704a = instance.getIV();
        aVar.f18705b = instance.doFinal(bArr);
        aVar.f18706c = e(aVar.a());
        return aVar;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    @TargetApi(23)
    public boolean p() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar instance2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        instance2.add(1, 25);
        if (this.f18695a.containsAlias("sps_aes_key")) {
            return false;
        }
        KeyGenerator instance3 = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "AndroidKeyStore");
        instance3.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("sps_aes_key", 3).setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal("CN = Secured Preference Store, O = Devliving Online")).setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE).setKeySize(256).setKeyValidityEnd(instance2.getTime()).setKeyValidityStart(instance.getTime()).setBlockModes(new String[]{"GCM"}).setEncryptionPaddings(new String[]{"NoPadding"}).setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false).build());
        instance3.generateKey();
        return true;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public boolean q(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchProviderException, UnrecoverableEntryException {
        String v = v("sps_aes_key");
        if (sharedPreferences.contains(v)) {
            return false;
        }
        KeyGenerator instance = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        instance.init(256);
        boolean commit = sharedPreferences.edit().putString(v, d(b(instance.generateKey().getEncoded()))).commit();
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(v("sps_data_in_compat"), true).apply();
        return commit;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public void r(Context context, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
        if (!this.f18700f) {
            p();
            return;
        }
        t(context);
        C();
        q(sharedPreferences);
        s(sharedPreferences);
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public boolean s(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) throws NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchProviderException, UnrecoverableEntryException, IOException {
        String v = v("sps_mac_key");
        if (sharedPreferences.contains(v)) {
            return false;
        }
        byte[] bArr = new byte[32];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(bArr);
        return sharedPreferences.edit().putString(v, d(b(bArr))).commit();
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public void t(Context context) throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, KeyStoreException {
        KeyPairGeneratorSpec keyPairGeneratorSpec;
        if (!this.f18695a.containsAlias("sps_rsa_key")) {
            Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar instance2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            instance2.add(1, 25);
            KeyPairGenerator instance3 = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                keyPairGeneratorSpec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context).setAlias("sps_rsa_key").setKeySize(2048).setKeyType("RSA").setEndDate(instance2.getTime()).setStartDate(instance.getTime()).setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE).setSubject(new X500Principal("CN = Secured Preference Store, O = Devliving Online")).build();
            } else {
                keyPairGeneratorSpec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context).setAlias("sps_rsa_key").setEndDate(instance2.getTime()).setStartDate(instance.getTime()).setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE).setSubject(new X500Principal("CN = Secured Preference Store, O = Devliving Online")).build();
            }
            instance3.initialize(keyPairGeneratorSpec);
            instance3.generateKeyPair();
        }
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public SecretKey u(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        String string = sharedPreferences.getString(v("sps_aes_key"), (String) null);
        if (string != null) {
            return new SecretKeySpec(a(c(string)), "AES");
        }
        return null;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public byte[] w() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] bArr = !this.f18700f ? new byte[12] : new byte[16];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(bArr);
        return bArr;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public SecretKey x(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        String string = sharedPreferences.getString(v("sps_mac_key"), (String) null);
        if (string != null) {
            return new SecretKeySpec(a(c(string)), "HmacSHA256");
        }
        return null;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public <T extends Exception> boolean y(T t) {
        return (t instanceof KeyStoreException) || (t instanceof UnrecoverableEntryException) || (t instanceof InvalidKeyException) || (t instanceof IllegalStateException) || ((t instanceof IOException) && t.getCause() != null && (t.getCause() instanceof BadPaddingException));
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: package-private */
    public List<String> z() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"sps_aes_key", "sps_rsa_key"});
    }
}
```

this is an example of the request
[image]

and this is the Cipher in the decompiled apk

[image]

I've tried to inject the mobile application using a JS code using Frida

```
console.log("Script loaded");
Java.perform(function x() {
//hooking SecretKeySpec's constructor to get the SecretKeySpec
var secret_key_spec = Java.use("javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec");
secret_key_spec.$init.overload("[B", "java.lang.String").implementation = function (x, y) {
    //send('{"my_type" : "KEY"}', new Uint8Array(x));
    console.log(Uint8Array(x));
}
});
```

But I always get an error:

[image]

and then I got an Idea which I may be wrong, I was thinking to inject the Encryption JAVA file with a POST request with payload secret key to my Webhook, then recompile the mobile application and push to my device machine and test if I can receive the request so I can found the secret key there.

If someone which a big knowledge in reverse engineer can help! or if there any chance that can this be solved it will be super amazing!

Thanks <3

Comment: check the variable `f18699e` anyway this site is enouraging to ask specific questions, not freely collaborating on potencially illegal activity (did you agree with the eula/license terms)..

Comment: @gusto2 yes, this a CTF made by the company that I'm trying to get it's secrets keys, we still have 10 days left before we submit our results.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error i needed to

- Install leastest python version and pip3
- Install frida using

  `pip3 install frida`
- install frida tools

  `sudo pip3 install frida-tools`

You can see this way you must use sudo to avoid  bugs **https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/1355#issuecomment-739974712**

Example of working code if you needed **https://n00b.sh/posts/aes-killer-mobile-app-demo/**